# Newtonsoft Json Schema

Tags: json, json.net, schema

On the `Newtonsoft` home page about the `Schema Builder` it was said, you can use the schema builder 1000 times an hour if you have the MIT license included. How can I include this license in my project.

At the moment I get the following **error message:**

> The free-quota limit of 10 schema generations per hour has been
>   reached. Please visit http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema to upgrade
>   to a commercial license.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code is this fragment:

```
   public static void RegisterLicense(string license)
    {
        ReleaseDateAttribute releaseDateAttribute = ReflectionUtils.GetAttribute<ReleaseDateAttribute>(typeof(LicenseHelpers).Assembly());

        RegisterLicense(license, releaseDateAttribute.ReleaseDate);
    }
```

Did you contact NewtonSoft and get a license key to pass to that function?

Comment: I did not get a license. I'd like to license with the MIT one. 1000 free. Don't know why i get the message about 10 quotas. Thanks again.

Comment: @JensGühmann It is about 1000 validations against schema per hour, not generate or build schemas. Build of schemas are limited to 10 per hour.

Answer (score 0):

Since building of schemas is limited to 10 per hour. We used NuGet package ***NJsonSchema***. Using this package we generated schema and used Newtonsoft to validate them. Check below code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using NJsonSchema.Generation;

internal class Program
{
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Using NJson
    var settings = new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings();
    var generator = new NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator(settings);

    var expectedJsonSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(Rootobject));

    string generatedSchema = expectedJsonSchema.ToJson();
    //Console.WriteLine(generatedSchema);

    JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(generatedSchema);

    IList<string> messages = null;
    string responseJsonValue = @"{""menu"": {  ""id"": ""file"",
""value"": ""File"",
""popup"": {
""menuitem"": [
  {""value"": ""New"", ""onclick"": ""CreateNewDoc()""},
  {""value"": ""Open"", ""onclick"": ""OpenDoc()""},
  {""value"": ""Close"", ""onclick"": ""CloseDoc()""}
]}}}";

    //For JSON object - schema validation
    if (responseJsonValue.Trim().StartsWith("{") && responseJsonValue.Trim().EndsWith("}"))
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJsonValue);
        bool isSchemaValid = jObject.IsValid(schema, out messages);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
}


//POCO class for JSON string
public class Rootobject
{
public Menu menu { get; set; }
}
public class Menu
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string value { get; set; }
public Popup popup { get; set; }
}
public class Popup
{
public Menuitem[] menuitem { get; set; }
}
public class Menuitem
{
public string value { get; set; }
public string onclick { get; set; }
}
```

Error message - The free-quota limit of 10 schema generations per hour has been reached. Please visit http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema to upgrade to a commercial license.